# Installed Ruby, but installing RubyGems does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I just installed ruby on Ubuntu by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```

Then I downloaded RubyGems, extracted it, and navigated to that directory.  When I typed this command:

```
ruby setup.rb or sudo ruby setup.rb
```

I got this error:

```
The program 'ruby' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

How should I invoke my Ruby installation?  Should I reboot?  Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is twofold:

1. Ruby1.9 bundles rubygems by default so there is no need to install manually.
2. Ruby will proabably be installed as `ruby1.9.1-full` and you might need to rename manually to `ruby`. A good solution is to use [rvm](https://rvm.io).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
sudo ruby1.9.1 setup.rb
```

or

```
sudo ruby1.9.1-full setup.rb
```